# What does '$' mean in Excel formula? e.g: $B$4

Tags: vba, excel

What does `$B$4` mean in Excel?
Here's a sample code:

```
Cells(7, 15).Value = "=0.1*$B$4*M7*N7"
```

and

```
Cells(7, 17).Value = "=P7*1.3*$B$4"
```

Comment: http://www.notjustnumbers.co.uk/2011/05/excel-tip-dollar-sign-in-formula-fixing.html

Comment: Sorry, but this is easily googlable. https://www.google.com/?q=dollar+in+excel+formula#q=dollar+in+excel+formula

Comment: yes, at first i thought '$B$4' is a function as a whole but it turns out that it's only the dollar ($) sign, so nothing useful came up when i googled "what does $B$4 in excel mean?". The title of this question also referred to '$b$4' but i changed to the current title and put $b$4 as an example when i found out the answer.

Comment: For the record, this is now the first result in Google. :) Reasons why not to make "this is easily google-able" comments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `$` sign causes the cell column or row or both in a formula to be fixed.

That is, if you drag the formula cell horizontally or vertically in order to copy the formula, Excel will not adjust this value.

For example :

```
 Cell   Formula 
  A0     =$B4
```

If I drag this horizontally I will get :

```
 Cell   Formula 
  B0     =$B4
  C0     =$B4
```

If I drag this vertically I will get :

```
 Cell   Formula 
  A1     =$B5
  A2     =$B6
```

Without the dollar sign :

If I drag this horizontally I will get :

```
 Cell   Formula 
  B0     =C4
  C0     =D4
```

If I drag this vertically I will get :

```
 Cell   Formula 
  A1     =B5
  A2     =B6
```

Answer (score 2):

*The dollar sign allows you to fix either the row, the column or both on any cell reference, by preceding the column or row with the dollar sign.*

In your example you fix the column to **B** and the row to **4** because you probably want to take in consideration only that cell for your formula.